# Curl : problem when I try to redirect output to file

Tags: linux, bash, curl

I use this curl command to download a setup.exe :

```
curl -k -u login:Password -O "https://url/to/my/setup.exe"
```

I want to get the time total :

```
curl -s -w 'total : %{time_total}\n' -k -u login:Password -O "https://url/to/my/setup.exe"
total : 41.165108
```

I want to redirect the output ( total : 41.165108 ) in an external file. I try :

```
curl -o test.txt -s -w 'total : %{time_total}\n' -k -u login:Password -O "https://url/to/my/setup.exe"
```

```
curl -s -w 'total : %{time_total}\n' -k -u login:Password -O "https://url/to/my/setup.exe" > test.txt
```

But it doesn't work...

Someone to show me ?

Thanks !

Comment: Have you tried `>test.txt` as part of the command line? the `-w` option goes to stdout, you're redirecting the data output with the `-O` option

Answer (score 1):

Just combine the two things you've tried:

```
curl -s -w 'total : %{time_total}\n' -k -u login:Password \
    -O "https://url/to/my/setup.exe" -o setup.exe > total.txt
#                                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~ ~~~~~~~~~~~
```

- `setup.exe` will contain the downloaded file
- `total.txt` will contain the total

The `-o` doesn't influence where the output of `-w` goes.

Answer (score 0):

The `-o` parameter is in lowercase, and the file to output to, is to be entered after the parameter, an example is below,

`curl -K myconfig.txt -o output.txt`